# What is efficient way to Write and Read mixed data as byte on file

Tags: java, file-io, byte

I have a huge HashMap data structure that I want to compress its values and write them and hashmap keys as byte on files. Also I want to read this data from some of the files and decompress them and put them on a Hashmap too.

I implemented all parts except writing and reading these data from a file.

I explained what I did until now.

I defined my hashmap as `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Posting>>`

The Posting is defined:

```
class Posting {

 public int documentId;
 public double score;
 public Posting(){
     documentId=-1;
     score=1;
 }

 public Posting(int docId, double scr){
     documentId = docId;
     score = scr;
 }
```

After I filled the Hashmap I compress all docIds of a key and saved them as `byte[]`and compress the scr as `int[]`. Then I want to write this information in the following order in the file.

```
key(String){seperator1}docIds(byte[]){seprator2}scores(int[]){seperator3}
key2(String){seperator1}docIds1(byte[]){seprator2}scores1(int[]){seperator3}
```

I use "." as a seperate in my implementation.

I wrote and read these data on file based on following codes

```
DataOutputStream os= new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file,true));
                os.writeBytes(key);
                os.writeBytes(".");
                int n = finalInvertedLists.get(key).size();
                for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) { 
                    Posting p = finalInvertedLists.get(key).get(i);
                    os.writeByte(p.documentId);
                    os.writeBytes(".");
                    os.writeByte((int)p.score);
                    os.writeBytes(".");
                }
                os.close();
```

reading the posting list for given word based on the following code

```
DataInputStream is= new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(str));
        String line="";
        while((line = is.readLine()) != null)
        {
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line,".");

            if(tokens.nextToken().equals(word))
            {
                while(tokens.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    int id=Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
                    double score= Double.parseDouble(tokens.nextToken());
                    //int docLength= Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
                    postings.add(new Posting(id,score)); //, docLength ));  
                }
            }
        }
       is.close();
```

I cannot read correctly; I think; maybe I did not write correctly too.
**I dont know how to write this data on file as byte then can retrieve them efficiently.**
I hope my mistake is not silly since I start working with file on Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary files usually do not use seperators or delimiters. Instead they add meta data that specify the length of a data field or the number of entries in a list.

In Java you can use [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) which has methods like `writeUTF(..)`. It acts exactly as I wrote, first the number of bytes is written to the steram and afterwards the 
string content.

In your case you could write eack entry, starting with the key, then ten an int for the number of Postings in the list and the for each Posting the fields.

For reading the is of course a matching DataInputStream available.

Comment: Writing the length number is also increase the size of file; is n't it? because I compress to save space

Comment: Yes, but usually the required space is negligible and anyway this data is necessary. Using separators would require space, too. How may entries do you have more than a million?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My entities is not more than million.

Comment: Would you please help me how to write this data on file

Comment: @Fatima: I am sorry but you really could do a little bit on your own. Stackoverflow is full of examples how to write to a file using DataOutputStream. Just search for `java write file dataoutputstream`

Comment: I cannot upvote since I am new in stackoverfelow.Also, your answer is not the complete solution for my question. Therefore; I cannot accept your answer.

Comment: @Fatima: Stackoverflow is here for helping you, not for letting others doing your job. BTW: According to the FAQ accepting an answer means that this was the most helpful answer not that someone presented a fully working solution to you...